# How do I use useRef or something else to make the auth variable available throughout the program without it changing after re-rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I can use it with class component using this.auth, but how do I accomplish that using function based component and hooks

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const GoogleAuth = () => {
    const [ isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn ] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
            window.gapi.client
                .init({
                    clientId: '#ID',
                    scope: 'email'
                })
                .then(() => {
                    //THIS AUTH VARIABLE
                    const auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                    setIsSignedIn(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                    auth.isSignedIn.listen(onAuthChange);
                });
        });
    }, []);

    const onAuthChange = () => {
        setIsSignedIn(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    };
```

Comment: You could achieve that by using React Context API

Answer (score 0):

The hook equivalent of `this.auth` would be `useRef`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

const GoogleAuth = () => {
    const auth = useRef()
    const [ isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn ] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
            window.gapi.client
                .init({
                    clientId: '#ID',
                    scope: 'email'
                })
                .then(() => {
                    auth.current = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                    setIsSignedIn(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                    auth.current.isSignedIn.listen(onAuthChange);
                });
        });
    }, []);

    const onAuthChange = () => {
        setIsSignedIn(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    };
```

However since this is auth data, you might also be interested to look at `useContext` or maybe having a custom hook that will store it in the sessionStorage or localStorage.